# C# объединение и сумма одинаковых элементов в List

Tags: c#, list

подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить сумму одинаковых элементов в двух списках? И добавить в конечный список уникальные элементы?

Пример :

```
 class Salary
    {
        public string nickname; // имя
        public double amount;   // сумма
    }

           List<Salary> workers1 = new List<Salary>();
            workers1.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Vladimir", amount = 455.75 });
            workers1.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Elena", amount = 214.20 });
            workers1.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Oleg", amount = 199.85 });

           List<Salary> workers2 = new List<Salary>();
            workers2.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Elena", amount = 18.45 });
            workers2.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Vladimir", amount = 579.04 });
            workers2.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Oleg", amount = 322.95 });
            workers2.Add(new Salary() { nickname = "Anton", amount = 55 });
```

Объединить пробовал :

```
 workers1 = workers1.Union(workers2).ToList();
```

Как сюда можно добавить операцию суммирования? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте группировку для получения суммы по имени.

```
var result = workers1.Concat(workers2).GroupBy(x => x.nickname)
        .Select(x => new Salary() {nickname = x.Key, amount = x.Sum(z=>z.amount)})
        .ToList();

foreach (var w in result.OrderBy(x => x.nickname))
    Console.WriteLine($"{w.nickname} - {w.amount}");
```

Вывод

```
Anton - 55
Elena - 232,65
Oleg - 522,8
Vladimir - 1034,79
```